# Is there a bug with SparkContext() and SparkConf()

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

When I try to init SparkContext with SparkConf as below:

```
from pyspark import *
from pyspark.streaming import *

cfg = SparkConf().setMaster('yarn').setAppName('MyApp')
sc = SparkContext(conf=cfg)
print(sc.getConf().getAll())

rdd = sc.parallelize(list('abcdefg')).map(lambda x:(x,1))
print(rdd.collect())
```

The output show that it does not run with yarn:

```
[(u'spark.master', u'local[10]'), ...]
```

It used the config which in $SPARK_HOME/conf/spark-defaults.conf:

```
spark.master local[10]
```

My computer:
Python2.7.2 Spark2.1.0

---

Then I run the same code in spark2.0.2 and SparkConf() works as well

So it is really a bug ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To utilize yarn, you should specify whether the driver should run on the master or one of the worker nodes.

yarn-client will execute driver on the master node

```
SparkConf().setMaster('yarn-client')
```

yarn-cluster will execute driver on one of the worker nodes

```
SparkConf().setMaster('yarn-cluster')
```

[Here](https://docs.continuum.io/anaconda-cluster/howto/spark-yarn) is an example for running in yarn-client mode.